# How to inject dates to react-dates library the other way around?

Tags: next.js, react-dates

I am building a project using DateRangePicker in [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates).

Is there a way I can inject dates to DateRangePicker on the other way around?

Suppose I get dates **check_in: 2020-11-03, check_out: 2020-11-15** from query parameters and I want to display check-in, check-out dates in react-dates.

I have searched google and issue page on github but could not find anything helpful.

Is there a props supported by react-dates itself to make thing work?